# Как правильно задать размер фигуры/текста на Canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

У меня сейчас задается размер текста  `mPaint.setTextSize(15)`, но мне нужно, что бы он был `15sp`, как правильно нужно перевести/указать `15sp`, что сделать, что бы на экране правильно отобразилась надпись  нужного размера? 
Пробовала использовать `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.letters_height)`, но на экране надпись получается меньше, чем 15sp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Paint.setTextSize()` принимает значение размера текста в пикселях. Чтобы задать размер в других единицах измерения, вам надо перевести их в пиксели. Делается это так:
из ресурсов:

```
int sizeInPx = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.letters_height);
```

Из числа:

```
int sp = 20;
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: @Lucky_girl, `TypedValue` содержит константы для всех типов. Посмотрите там